# SQLAlchemy, filter out rows that do not fit a condition but use adjacent column of that row if no condition fits

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I could have thousands of these tables with a number of different dates.

I have joined two tables on Fee.id, I understand that I am getting a duplicated Order.id because of the two different rows in the Fee table that is linked to the same Order.id.

| Order.id | Order.created | Fee.date_min | Fee.date_max | Fee.fee | Fee.id | Price | Price+fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 108 | 2021-02-24 | 2018-01-01 | 2019-12-31 | 10 | 1 | 9.99 | 19.99 |
| 108 | 2021-02-24 | 2020-01-01 | 2021-04-01 | 1 | 1 | 9.99 | 10.99 |
| 109 | 2021-02-26 | None | None | None | None | 6.99 | 6.99 |

Would I then need to use .filter() logic or is this something to do in the query itself?

I have tried

```
.filter(and_(PaymentMethodsDate.payment_date_min <= Orders.date_created,
             PaymentMethodsDate.payment_date_max >= Orders.date_created))
```

| Order.id | Order.created | Fee.date_min | Fee.date_max | Fee.fee | Fee.id | Price | Price+fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 108 | 2021-02-24 | 2020-01-01 | 2021-04-01 | 1 | 1 | 9.99 | 10.99 |

but I am only left with the Orders that fit this condition when I need all the orders that fit the condition plus the orders that do not but which are not of the same id as the one in the filter.  My goal is for an output like below

| Order.id | Order.created | Fee.date_min | Fee.date_max | Fee.fee | Fee.id | Price | Price+fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 108 | 2021-02-24 | 2020-01-01 | 2021-04-01 | 1 | 1 | 9.99 | 10.99 |
| 109 | 2021-02-26 | None | None | None | None | 6.99 | 6.99 |

I know I am missing something obvious, but I can't work it out.  Is there a way to remove a row that doesn't fit a condition?

EDIT -----
I thought I had worked it out, I thought that it would work if I used the or function and have the second condition be Fee.date_min==None to select the rest that doesn't fall into the first condition.

```
.filter(or_(
    Order.created.between(Fee.date_min, Fee.date_max),
    Fee.date_min==None
    ))
```

However, I have now run into the problem where by the Order is completely removed using this filter if no dates match and I need to use adjacent columns from that row to get a general fee (Gen_fee) if the date specific one doesn't exist.
I need it to look like it does below.

| Order.id | Order.created | Fee.date_min | Fee.date_max | Fee.fee | Gen_fee | Fee.id | Price | Price+fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 110 | 2021-02-24 | 2020-01-01 | 2021-02-01 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 9.99 | 14.99 |
| 111 | 2021-02-26 | None | None | None | None | None | 6.99 | 6.99 |

I am slowly getting there:

```py
.filter(or_(
            case([(
                Order.created.between(Fee.date_min, Fee.date_max), # IF
                Order.created.between(Fee.date_min, Fee.date_max)  # THEN
            )], else_=(~Order.created.between(Fee.date_min, Fee.date_max))),
        Fee.date_min == None
            ))
```

I used a case function to provide the columns that don't fit into the date, but my current issue is I only need one column (as I will be summing potentially thousands of rows) and not two (or more), is there a way to limit the column to one?

EDIT ---
I think I may have to use two queries and combine them to achieve it somehow in a subquery.  I will update if I am successful.

EDIT ---
This is a good resource of subquery examples and a good explanation of the process of what I think I need to do - https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/nested-queries-with-sqlalchemy-orm